# How to auto complete the step definitions in Karate

Tags: autocomplete, cucumber, karate

We all know that Karate has built in Gherkin commands Given, When, Then. And user does not have to write the Step definitions for the same. Is it possible that I can get a auto complete list of all the stepd's as and when I start typing in similar to what we have in traditional cucumber.

For ex:
If i start typing "match" it will list down the step definition for me in the auto complete dropdown

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the IDE + plugin combination that you have. You get some level of autocomplete in [Eclipse and IntelliJ](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support) - see below an example of IntelliJ:

[image]

That said, let me set expectations. Karate is a loosely-typed scripting language and currently does not have the level of "intellisense" etc. that you may be used to in other languages. This is [on the roadmap](https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-22529505), so maybe you would like to contribute code :)

The 2 reasons why we don't consider this the highest priority is

- the debug support: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1252817691963830272
- the HTML report: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1237797240686522369 (for e.g. a common workflow is to run a single test locally, and if it fails, refresh the report and you immediately see the problem areas.

Comment: IDE I am using is Eclipse IDE

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot Peter for helping out.